# Overriding DataTables Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have this JavaScript code.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    function getNameSpecsSize(data, type, dataToSet) {
        return data[3] + ", " + data[4] + ", " + data[5];
    }

    function getWOandSheet(data, type, dataToSet) {
        return data[10] + " / " + data[11];
    }
    
    var table = $('#material_used').dataTable( {
        "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        "scrollY": 350,
        "scrollX": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Scripts/server-response-mat-used.php",
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback,
                "error": function () {
                    alert( 'No data available / No matching records found' );
                    window.history.back();
                }
            })
        },
        "aoColumns": [
                {"data": "1", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "2", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": getNameSpecsSize, "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "6", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "7", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "8", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "9", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": getWOandSheet, "sClass": "align_center"},
                { "mData": null , //its null here because history column will contain the mRender
                "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ) {
                    return '<a href="link.php?c='+data[0]+'">Edit</a> / <a href="link.php?c='+data[0]+'">Delete</a>';}
                }
            ],
        "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        lengthMenu: [
            [ -1 ],
            [ 'Show all' ]
        ],
        buttons: [
            'pageLength',
            'print',
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5',
            'colvis'
        ]
    });
});

</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .align_right { text-align: right; }
    .align_center { text-align: center; }
</style>
```

```html
<table id="material_used" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="10%"><div align="center"><font size="2">A</font></div></th>
    <th width="8%"><div align="center"><font size="2">B</font></div></th>
    <th width="15%"><div align="center"><font size="2">C, D, E</font></div></th>
    <th width="3%"><div align="center"><font size="2">F</font></div></th>
    <th width="10%"><div align="center"><font size="2">L</font></div></th>
    <th width="15%"><div align="center"><font size="2">G</font></div></th>
    <th width="15%"><div align="center"><font size="2">H</font></div></th>
    <th width="15%"><div align="center"><font size="2">I / J</font></div></th>
    <th width="10%"><div align="center"><font size="2">K</font></div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I made to show the error message *No data available / No matching records found* in localhost server, but when I run the code on my server, the error won't show.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Have you verified that the AJAX request is firing?  One way to do this is to look at F12 developer tools in your browser.  Look at the Network tab and verify POST is being sent to the url.

Comment: @devlincarnate Yes, absolutely. The POST is sent to the url. and I can see the result is null. I added to the code if result is null / error then show the message. Inside localhost server, the error is appear, but after I uploaded the file to my server, the error won't show, but still the POST is sent to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like DataTables **fnServerData** didn't work in my server, so I've came with AJAX code that check whether the response of the url is giving me *null* response or not when the page is loaded / ready.

So here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server-response.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if (response == "null"){
                alert( 'No data available / No matching records found' );
                    window.history.back();
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

When the page is ready, the script will send the POST request and read the response from the url. If I get null response, the alert dialog will pop up and the page will redirect automatically to the previous page before DataTables send the AJAX and read JSON response (which is null) to the same url I used in the code, so the error message from DataTables won't show up.